# How old is that map?

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

Referencing [xkcd 1688](https://xkcd.com/1688/):
[image: guide]

Your task is to deduct the age of a map by asking the user questions. These question must be exactly the same as in the xkcd guide, except from the capitalisation and additional newline(s). Additionally, you should give the user some options to choose from, which don't have to be in the order as in the xkcd image. If the input doesn't match any of the expected answers, your program/function may behave in any undefined way. At the end, you should output the year/timespan the map was created.

### Examples (`>` denotes input, but you may choose something else):

#### Example 1:

```
ISTANBUL OR CONSTANTINOPLE?
(CONSTANTINOPLE, NEITHER, ISTANBUL)

>ISTANBUL

DOES THE SOVIET UNION EXISTS?
(YES, NO)

>NO

ZAIRE?
OR: 'HONG KONG (UK)'
(YES, NO)

>NO

SERBIA / MONTENEGRO ARE?
(ONE COUNTRY, TWO COUNTRIES)

>TWO COUNTRIES

HOW MANY SUDANS ARE THERE?
(ONE, TWO)

>ONE

2007-11
```

#### Example 2:

```
ISTANBUL OR CONSTANTINOPLE?
(CONSTANTINOPLE, NEITHER, ISTANBUL)

>how are you

error
```

Comment: I see you already golffed Germanies

Comment: Does the choice of question to ask need to depend on previous answers, like a flow chart, or can the code simply ask all of the questions?

Comment: You have to follow the flowchart exactly as in the xkcd.

Comment: Can you ask for the answers in code (e.g. Istanbul (1) or Constantinople (2) or Neither (3)?)

Comment: You may give the answers with an associated number and expect a number as input.

Comment: [explanations + transcript](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1688:_Map_Age_Guide)

Comment: Yeah, a transcript of all the questions would incline me to try this but at the mo far too exhaustive an exercise. But, having said that, what a fascinating flow chart. +1 for such an interesting base material.

Answer (score 8):

## Game Maker Language (GM 8.0), <s>10262</s> <s>10228</s> <s>10152</s> <s>10115</s> <s>8746</s> 1 + 8699 = 8700 bytes

We define a script named `X` (1 byte). Each question is labelled with an integer. `X` takes such an integer, prompts the user with the corresponding question, and either returns the appropriate message or calls the next question. At each question, the user is prompted for an integer corresponding to the possible options. If the user does not match any of the options, then the prompt is exited.

```
A=argument1 Y="##YES (1), NO (2)"I="IS THERE A BIG LAKE IN THE MIDDLE OF "H="HOW MANY "switch argument0{case H:return show_message(A)break
case I:return get_integer(A,1)break
case 1:switch X(I,"ISTANBUL OR CONSTANTINOPLE##CONSTANTINOPLE (1), NEITHER (2), ISTANBUL(3)"){case 1:X(2)break case 2:X(19)break case 3:X(74)}break
case 2:switch X(I,"DO ANY OF THESE EXIST?#- INDEPENDENT CANADA#- US TERRITORY OF ALASKA#- TOKYO"+Y){case 2:X(3)break case 1:X(11)}break
case 3:switch X(I,"THE HOLY ROMAN EMPIRE?"+Y){case 1:X(H,"1805 OR EARLIER (BEFORE THIS POINT, THE MODERN IDEA OF A COMPLETE POLITICAL MAP OF THE WORLD GETS HARD TO APPLY.)")break case 2:X(4)}break
case 4:switch X(I,"THE UNITED STATES?"+Y){case 2:X(H,"HOW SURE ARE YOU THAT THIS MAP IS IN ENGLISH")break case 1:X(5)}break
case 5:switch X(I,"TEXAS IS...##PART OF MEXICO (1), INDEPENDENT (2), PART OF THE US (3)"){case 1:X(6)break case 2:X(H,"1834-45")break case 3:X(9)}break
case 6:switch X(I,"FLORIDA IS PART OF...##SPAIN (1), THE US (2)"){case 1:X(7)break case 2:X(8)}break
case 7:switch X(I,"PARAGUAY?"+Y){case 2:X(H,"1806H0")break case 1:X(H,"1811H7")}break
case 8:switch X(I,"VENEZUELA AND/OR ECUADOR?"+Y){case 2:X(H,"1818-29")break case 1:X(H,"1830-33")}break
case 9:switch X(I,"DOES RUSSIA BORDER THE SEA OF JAPAN?"+Y){case 2:X(10)break case 1:X(H,"1858-67")}break
case 10:switch X(I,"THE US'S SOUTHERN BORDER LOOKS...##WEIRD (1), NORMAL (2)"){case 1:X(H,"1846-53")break case 2:X(H,"1854-56")}break
case 11:switch X(I,"SOUTH AFRICA?"+Y){case 2:X(12)break case 1:X(16)}break
case 12:switch X(I,"RHODESIA?"+Y){case 2:X(13)break case 1:X(15)}break
case 13:switch X(I,"IS BOLIVIA LANDLOCKED?"+Y){case 2:X(14)break case 1:X(H,"1884-95")}break
case 14:switch X(I,'"BUDA" AND "PEST" OR "BUDAPEST"?##BUDA AND PEST (1), BUDAPEST (2)'){case 1:X(H,"1868-72")break case 2:X(H,"1873-83")}break
case 15:switch X(I,"IS NORWAY PART OF SWEDEN?"+Y){case 1:X(H,"1896H905")break case 2:X(H,"1906-09")}break
case 16:switch X(I,"AUSTRIA-HUNGARY?"+Y){case 1:X(17)break case 2:X(18)}break
case 17:switch X(I,"ALBANIA?"+Y){case 2:X(H,"1910H2")break case 1:X(H,"1913H8")}break
case 18:switch X(I,"LENINGRAD?"+Y){case 2:X(H,"1919-23")break case 1:X(H,"1924-29")}break
case 19:switch X(I,"DOES THE OTTOMAN EMPIRE EXIST?"+Y){case 1:X(2)break case 2:X(20)}break
case 20:switch X(I,"THE SOVIET UNION?"+Y){case 2:X(21)break case 1:X(63)}break
case 21:switch X(I,"NORTH KOREA?"+Y){case 2:X(22)break case 1:X(56)}break
case 22:switch X(I,"SAINT TRIMBLE'S ISLAND?"+Y){case 2:X(23)break case 1:X(H,"NO, I MADE THAT ONE UP.")}break
case 23:switch X(I,"IS JAN MAYEN PART OF THE KINGDOM OF NORWAY?##NOT YET (1), WHAT? (2), YES (3)"){case 1:X(2)break case 2:X(24)break case 3:X(49)}break
case 24:switch X(I,"CAN YOU SEE THE FAMILIAR CONTINENTS?"+Y){case 1:X(25)break case 2:X(31)}break
case 25:switch X(I,"THIS SOUNDS LIKE A PHYSICAL MAP OR SATELLITE PHOTO.##YES, THAT'S IT (1)"){case 1:X(26)}break
case 26:switch X(I,"IS LAKE CHAD MISSING?"+Y){case 2:X(27)break case 1:X(30)}break
case 27:switch X(I,"HOW FAR EAST DO THE AMERICAN PRAIRIES REACH?##INDIANA (1), THE MISSISSIPPI (2), NEBRASKA (3), WHAT PRAIRIES? (4)"){case 1:X(H,"BEFORE 1830")break case 2:X(H,"1830s-80s")break case 3:X(28)break case 4:X(29)}break
case 28:switch X(I,I+"SOUTHERN CALIFORNIA? (CREATED BY MISTAKE)"+Y){case 2:X(H,"1860sH900s")break case 1:X(H,"1910s")}break
case 29:switch X(I,I+"GHANA? (CREATED ON PURPOSE)"+Y){case 2:X(H,"1920s-50s")break case 1:X(H,"1960s-70s")}break
case 30:switch X(I,"IS THE ARAL SEA MISSING?"+Y){case 2:X(H,"1970s-90s")break case 1:X(H,"2000s+")}break
case 31:switch X(I,'RIVERS "SIRION" OR "ANDUIN"?'+Y){case 1:X(32)break case 2:X(36)}break
case 32:switch X(I,"MORDOR?"+Y){case 2:X(33)break case 1:X(34)}break
case 33:switch X(I,"BELERIAND?"+Y){case 1:X(H,"FIRST AGE")break case 2:X(H,"EARLY SECOND AGE")}break
case 34:switch X(I,"NÚMENOR?"+Y){case 1:X(H,"LATE SECOND AGE")break case 2:X(35)}break
case 35:switch X(I,"THE FOREST EAST OF THE MISTY MOUNTAINS IS...##GREENWOOD THE GREAT (1), MIRKWOOD (2), THE WOOD OF GREENLEAVES (3)"){case 1:X(H,"EARLY THIRD AGE")break case 2:X(H,"LATE THIRD AGE")break case 3:X(H,"FOURTH AGE")}break
case 36:switch X(I,"CAIR PARAVEL?"+Y){case 1:X(37)break case 2:X(41)}break
case 37:switch X(I,"CALORMEN?"+Y){case 2:X(38)break case 1:X(40)}break
case 38:switch X(I,"LOTTA ISLANDS?"+Y){case 2:X(39)break case 1:X(H,"DAWN TREADER")}break
case 39:switch X(I,"BERUNA##FORD (1), BRIDGE (2)"){case 1:X(H,"THE LION, THE WITCH, AND THE WARDROBE")break case 2:X(H,"PRINCE CASPIAN")}break
case 40:switch X(I,"WEIRD RECURSIVE HEAVEN?"+Y){case 2:X(H,"ONE OF THE RANDOM LATER BOOKS")break case 1:X(H,"THE LAST BATTLE")}break
case 41:switch X(I,"MOSSFLOWER?"+Y){case 1:X(H,"REDWALL")break case 2:X(42)}break
case 42:switch X(I,"IS THE WORLD ON THE BACK OF A TURTLE?"+Y){case 1:X(H,"DISCWORLD")break case 2:X(43)}break
case 43:switch X(I,"ARE YOU SURE THIS IS A MAP?"+Y){case 1:X(44)break case 2:X(46)}break
case 44:switch X(I,"DID YOU MAKE IT YOURSELF?##YES (1)"){case 1:X(45)}break
case 45:X(I,"IT'S VERY NICE.##THANK YOU! (1)")break
case 46:switch X(I,"IS IT TRYING TO BITE YOU?"+Y){case 2:X(47)break case 1:X(48)}break
case 47:switch X(I,"IS IT LARGER THAN A BREADBOX?"+Y+", ABOUT THE SAME (3)"){case 1:X(H,"TUBA")break case 2:X(H,"STAPLER")break case 3:X(H,"BREADBOX")}break
case 48:switch X(I,"IF YOU LET IT GO, WHAT DOES IT DO?##HISSES AND RUNS AWAY (1), SCREECHES AND FLAPS AROUND THE ROOM BREAKING THINGS (2)"){case 1:X(H,"CAT")break case 2:X(H,"SEAGULL")}break
case 49:switch X(I,"PAKISTAN?"+Y){case 2:X(50)break case 1:X(52)}break
case 50:switch X(I,H+"GERMANYS ARE THERE?##ONE (1), ONE, BUT IT'S HUGE (2), TWO (3)"){case 1:X(51)break case 2:X(H,"1941-45")break case 3:X(H,"1946-47")}break
case 51:switch X(I,"PERSIA OR IRAN?##PERSIA (1), IRAN (2)"){case 1:X(H,"1930-34")break case 2:X(H,"1935-40")}break
case 52:switch X(I,"CAMBODIA?"+Y){case 2:X(53)break case 1:X(55)}break
case 53:switch X(I,"ERITREA IS A PART OF...##ITALY (1), ETHIOPIA (2)"){case 1:X(54)break case 2:X(H,"1952-53")}break
case 54:switch X(I,"CANADA IS...##MISSING A PIECE (1), FINE (2)"){case 1:X(H,"1948")break case 2:X(H,"1949-52")}break
case 55:switch X(I,"THE UNITED ARAB REPUBLIC?"+Y){case 2:X(H,"1954-57")break case 1:X(H,"1958-60")}break
case 56:switch X(I,'ZAIRE? OR: "HONG KONG (UK)"'+Y){case 1:X(H,"1992-96")break case 2:X(57)}break
case 57:switch X(I,"SERBIA AND MONTENEGRO ARE...##ONE COUNTRY (1), TWO COUNTRIES (2)"){case 1:X(58)break case 2:X(59)}break
case 58:switch X(I,"EAST TIMOR?"+Y){case 2:X(H,"1997-2001")break case 1:X(H,"2002-06")}break
case 59:switch X(I,H+"SUDANS ARE THERE?##ONE (1), TWO (2)"){case 1:X(H,"2007H1")break case 2:X(60)}break
case 60:switch X(I,"IS CRIMEA DISPUTED?"+Y){case 1:X(61)break case 2:X(H,"2012H3")}break
case 61:switch X(I,'"COLORADO" OR "DANGER-RADIOACTIVE EXCLUSION ZONE-AVOID"?##COLORADO (1), DANGER (2)'){case 1:X(H,"2014-21")break case 2:X(62)}break
case 62:switch X(I,"DOES THE WARNING MENTION THE SPIDERS?"+Y){case 2:X(H,"2022")break case 1:X(H,"2023 OR LATER")}break
case 63:switch X(I,"SAUDI ARABIA?"+Y){case 2:X(H,"1922-32")break case 1:X(64)}break
case 64:switch X(I,"IS MOST OF WEST AFRICA A GIANT FRENCH BLOB?"+Y){case 1:X(49)break case 2:X(65)}break
case 65:switch X(I,H+"VIETNAMS ARE THERE?##TWO (1), ONE (2)"){case 1:X(66)break case 2:X(69)}break
case 66:switch X(I,"BANGLADESH?"+Y){case 2:X(67)break case 1:X(H,"1972-75")}break
case 67:switch X(I,"IS THE AREA SOUTH OF LAKE VICTORIA...##BRITISH (1), TANGANYIKA (2), TANZANIA (3)"){case 1:X(68)break case 2:X(H,"1961-64")break case 3:X(H,"1965-71")}break
case 68:switch X(I,"THE TOWN ON I-25 BETWEEN ALBUQUERQUE AND EL PASO IS...##HOT SPRINGS (1), TRUTH OR CONSEQUENCES (2)"){case 1:X(H,"1948-49")break case 2:X(H,"1950-52")}break
case 69:switch X(I,"JIMMY CARTER IS...##BEING ATTACKED BY A GIANT SWIMMING RABBIT (1), FINE (2)"){case 1:X(H,"APRIL 20, 1979")break case 2:X(70)}break
case 70:switch X(I,"THE SINAI IS PART OF WHAT COUNTRY?## ISRAEL (1), MOSTLY ISRAEL (2), MOSTLY EGYPT (3), EGYPT (4)"){case 1:X(H,"1976-79")break case 2:X(H,"1980")break case 3:X(H,"1981")break case 4:X(71)}break
case 71:switch X(I,"WHAT'S THE CAPITAL OF MICRONESIA?## KOLONIA (1), PALIKIR (2)"){case 1:X(72)break case 2:X(73)}break
case 72:switch X(I,"REPUBLIC OF THE UPPER VOLTA OR BURKINA FASO?## UPPER VOLTA (1), BURKINA FASO (2)"){case 1:X(H,"1982-84")break case 2:X(H,"1985-88")}break
case 73:switch X(I,"(NUMBER OF YEMENS)+(NUMBER OF GERMANYS)=?## FOUR (1), THREE (2), TWO (3)"){case 1:X(H,"1989-EARLY 1990")break case 2:X(H,"MIDH990")break case 3:X(H,"LATE 1990H991")}break
case 74:switch X(I,"DOES THE SOVIET UNION EXIST?"+Y){case 1:X(64)break case 2:X(56)}break}
```

`#` is the newline character.

**How to run**

- New `.gmk` file
- Create a script `X` with contents as above
- Create an object `O` with Create Event: execute code: `X(1)`
- Create a room `R` and put one instance of `O` in it
- Run the game

**Golfing**

- The option `YES` now always precedes `NO`, and we define the string `Y="##YES (1), NO (2)"` for reuse.
- `"IS THERE A BIG LAKE IN THE MIDDLE OF "` and `"HOW MANY "` are long enough and occur sufficiently many times for abbreviation to pay off. They are assigned to `I` and `H`.
- In Game Maker, any user-defined function usually must be done in a separate script. The consensus on the [policy for counting bytes for multi-file programs](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4933/counting-bytes-for-multi-file-programs), was that *"If files are reused ... count the contents of that file as many times as you use it"*. As such, we use `X` itself, rather than a separate script, to abbreviate `get_integer` and `show_message`. Explicitly,

  - If `X` is called with zeroth argument `H`, then it returns `show_message` of the first argument.
  - If `X` is called with zeroth argument `I`, then it returns `get_integer` of the first argument, showing default input `1`.

**Ungolfed**, with options in the original order and no abbreviations at all:

```
// script X, takes node number, prompts question and returns message or calls X with next node number

switch argument0
{
case 1: switch get_integer("ISTANBUL OR CONSTANTINOPLE##CONSTANTINOPLE (1), NEITHER (2), ISTANBUL(3)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(2); break;
    case 2: X(19); break;
    case 3: X(74); break;
  }; break;
case 2: switch get_integer("DO ANY OF THESE EXIST?#- INDEPENDENT CANADA#- US TERRITORY OF ALASKA#- TOKYO##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(3); break;
    case 2: X(11); break;
  }; break;
case 3: switch get_integer("THE HOLY ROMAN EMPIRE?##YES (1), NO (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("1805 OR EARLIER (BEFORE THIS POINT, THE MODERN IDEA OF A COMPLETE POLITICAL MAP OF THE WORLD GETS HARD TO APPLY.)"); break;
    case 2: X(4); break;
  }; break;
case 4: switch get_integer("THE UNITED STATES?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("HOW SURE ARE YOU THAT THIS MAP IS IN ENGLISH"); break;
    case 2: X(5); break;
  }; break;
case 5: switch get_integer("TEXAS IS...##PART OF MEXICO (1), INDEPENDENT (2), PART OF THE US (3)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(6); break;
    case 2: show_message("1834-45"); break;
    case 3: X(9); break;
  }; break;
case 6: switch get_integer("FLORIDA IS PART OF...##SPAIN (1), THE US (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(7); break;
    case 2: X(8); break;
  }; break;
case 7: switch get_integer("PARAGUAY?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("1806-10"); break;
    case 2: show_message("1811-17"); break;
  }; break;
case 8: switch get_integer("VENEZUELA AND/OR ECUADOR?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("1818-29"); break;
    case 2: show_message("1830-33"); break;
  }; break;
case 9: switch get_integer("DOES RUSSIA BORDER THE SEA OF JAPAN?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(10); break;
    case 2: show_message("1858-67"); break;
  }; break;
case 10: switch get_integer("THE US'S SOUTHERN BORDER LOOKS...##WEIRD (1), NORMAL (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("1846-53"); break;
    case 2: show_message("1854-56"); break;
  }; break;
case 11: switch get_integer("SOUTH AFRICA?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(12); break;
    case 2: X(16); break;
  }; break;
case 12: switch get_integer("RHODESIA?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(13); break;
    case 2: X(15); break;
  }; break;
case 13: switch get_integer("IS BOLIVIA LANDLOCKED?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(14); break;
    case 2: show_message("1884-95"); break;
  }; break;
case 14: switch get_integer('"BUDA" AND "PEST" OR "BUDAPEST"?##BUDA AND PEST (1), BUDAPEST (2)',1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("1868-72"); break;
    case 2: show_message("1873-83"); break;
  }; break;
case 15: switch get_integer("IS NORWAY PART OF SWEDEN?##YES (1), NO (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("1896-1905"); break;
    case 2: show_message("1906-09"); break;
  }; break;
case 16: switch get_integer("AUSTRIA-HUNGARY?##YES (1), NO (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(17); break;
    case 2: X(18); break;
  }; break;
case 17: switch get_integer("ALBANIA?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("1910-12"); break;
    case 2: show_message("1913-18"); break;
  }; break;
case 18: switch get_integer("LENINGRAD?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("1919-23"); break;
    case 2: show_message("1924-29"); break;
  }; break;
case 19: switch get_integer("DOES THE OTTOMAN EMPIRE EXIST?##YES (1), NO (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(2); break;
    case 2: X(20); break;
  }; break;
case 20: switch get_integer("THE SOVIET UNION?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(21); break;
    case 2: X(63); break;
  }; break;
case 21: switch get_integer("NORTH KOREA?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(22); break;
    case 2: X(56); break;
  }; break;
case 22: switch get_integer("SAINT TRIMBLE'S ISLAND?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(23); break;
    case 2: show_message("NO, I MADE THAT ONE UP."); break;
  }; break;
case 23: switch get_integer("IS JAN MAYEN PART OF THE KINGDOM OF NORWAY?##NOT YET (1), WHAT? (2), YES (3)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(2); break;
    case 2: X(24); break;
    case 3: X(49); break;
  }; break;
case 24: switch get_integer("CAN YOU SEE THE FAMILIAR CONTINENTS?##YES (1), NO (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(25); break;
    case 2: X(31); break;
  }; break;
case 25: switch get_integer("THIS SOUNDS LIKE A PHYSICAL MAP OR SATELLITE PHOTO.##YES, THAT'S IT (1)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(26); break;
  }; break;
case 26: switch get_integer("IS LAKE CHAD MISSING?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(27); break;
    case 2: X(30); break;
  }; break;
case 27: switch get_integer("HOW FAR EAST DO THE AMERICAN PRAIRIES REACH?##INDIANA (1), THE MISSISSIPPI (2), NEBRASKA (3), WHAT PRAIRIES? (4)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("BEFORE 1830"); break;
    case 2: show_message("1830s-80s"); break;
    case 3: X(28); break;
    case 4: X(29); break;
  }; break;
case 28: switch get_integer("IS THERE A BIG LAKE IN THE MIDDLE OF SOUTHERN CALIFORNIA? (CREATED BY MISTAKE)##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("1860s-1900s"); break;
    case 2: show_message("1910s"); break;
  }; break;
case 29: switch get_integer("IS THERE A BIG LAKE IN THE MIDDLE OF GHANA? (CREATED ON PURPOSE)##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("1920s-50s"); break;
    case 2: show_message("1960s-70s"); break;
  }; break;
case 30: switch get_integer("IS THE ARAL SEA MISSING?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("1970s-90s"); break;
    case 2: show_message("2000s+"); break;
  }; break;
case 31: switch get_integer('RIVERS "SIRION" OR "ANDUIN"?##YES (1), NO (2)',1)
  {
    case 1: X(32); break;
    case 2: X(36); break;
  }; break;
case 32: switch get_integer("MORDOR?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(33); break;
    case 2: X(34); break;
  }; break;
case 33: switch get_integer("BELERIAND?##YES (1), NO (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("FIRST AGE"); break;
    case 2: show_message("EARLY SECOND AGE"); break;
  }; break;
case 34: switch get_integer("NÚMENOR?##YES (1), NO (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("LATE SECOND AGE"); break;
    case 2: X(35); break;
  }; break;
case 35: switch get_integer("THE FOREST EAST OF THE MISTY MOUNTAINS IS...##GREENWOOD THE GREAT (1), MIRKWOOD (2), THE WOOD OF GREENLEAVES (3)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("EARLY THIRD AGE"); break;
    case 2: show_message("LATE THIRD AGE"); break;
    case 3: show_message("FOURTH AGE"); break;
  }; break;
case 36: switch get_integer("CAIR PARAVEL?##YES (1), NO (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(37); break;
    case 2: X(41); break;
  }; break;
case 37: switch get_integer("CALORMEN?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(38); break;
    case 2: X(40); break;
  }; break;
case 38: switch get_integer("LOTTA ISLANDS?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(39); break;
    case 2: show_message("DAWN TREADER"); break;
  }; break;
case 39: switch get_integer("BERUNA##FORD (1), BRIDGE (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("THE LION, THE WITCH, AND THE WARDROBE"); break;
    case 2: show_message("PRINCE CASPIAN"); break;
  }; break;
case 40: switch get_integer("WEIRD RECURSIVE HEAVEN?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("ONE OF THE RANDOM LATER BOOKS"); break;
    case 2: show_message("THE LAST BATTLE"); break;
  }; break;
case 41: switch get_integer("MOSSFLOWER?##YES (1), NO (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("REDWALL"); break;
    case 2: X(42); break;
  }; break;
case 42: switch get_integer("IS THE WORLD ON THE BACK OF A TURTLE?##YES (1), NO (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("DISCWORLD"); break;
    case 2: X(43); break;
  }; break;
case 43: switch get_integer("ARE YOU SURE THIS IS A MAP?##YES (1), NO (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(44); break;
    case 2: X(46); break;
  }; break;
case 44: switch get_integer("DID YOU MAKE IT YOURSELF?##YES (1)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(45); break;
  }; break;
case 45: switch get_integer("IT'S VERY NICE.##THANK YOU! (1)",1)
  {
    case 1: break;
  }; break;
case 46: switch get_integer("IS IT TRYING TO BITE YOU?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(47); break;
    case 2: X(48); break;
  }; break;
case 47: switch get_integer("IS IT LARGER THAN A BREADBOX?##YES (1), NO (2), ABOUT THE SAME (3)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("TUBA") break;
    case 2: show_message("STAPLER") break;
    case 3: show_message("BREADBOX") break;
  }; break;
case 48: switch get_integer("IF YOU LET IT GO, WHAT DOES IT DO?##HISSES AND RUNS AWAY (1), SCREECHES AND FLAPS AROUND THE ROOM BREAKING THINGS (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("CAT") break;
    case 2: show_message("SEAGULL") break;
  }; break;
case 49: switch get_integer("PAKISTAN?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(50); break;
    case 2: X(52); break;
  }; break;
case 50: switch get_integer("HOW MANY GERMANYS ARE THERE?##ONE (1), ONE, BUT IT'S HUGE (2), TWO (3)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(51); break;
    case 2: show_message("1941-45") break;
    case 3: show_message("1946-47") break;
  }; break;
case 51: switch get_integer("PERSIA OR IRAN?##PERSIA (1), IRAN (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("1930-34") break;
    case 2: show_message("1935-40") break;
  }; break;
case 52: switch get_integer("CAMBODIA?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(53); break;
    case 2: X(55); break;
  }; break;
case 53: switch get_integer("ERITREA IS A PART OF...##ITALY (1), ETHIOPIA (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(54); break;
    case 2: show_message("1952-53"); break;
  }; break;
case 54: switch get_integer("CANADA IS...##MISSING A PIECE (1), FINE (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("1948"); break;
    case 2: show_message("1949-52"); break;
  }; break;
case 55: switch get_integer("THE UNITED ARAB REPUBLIC?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("1954-57"); break;
    case 2: show_message("1958-60"); break;
  }; break;
case 56: switch get_integer('ZAIRE? OR: "HONG KONG (UK)"##YES (1), NO (2)',1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("1992-96"); break;
    case 2: X(57); break;
  }; break;
case 57: switch get_integer("SERBIA AND MONTENEGRO ARE...##ONE COUNTRY (1), TWO COUNTRIES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(58); break;
    case 2: X(59); break;
  }; break;
case 58: switch get_integer("EAST TIMOR?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("1997-2001"); break;
    case 2: show_message("2002-06"); break;
  }; break;
case 59: switch get_integer("HOW MANY SUDANS ARE THERE?##ONE (1), TWO (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("2007-11"); break;
    case 2: X(60); break;
  }; break;
case 60: switch get_integer("IS CRIMEA DISPUTED?##YES (1), NO (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(61); break;
    case 2: show_message("2012-13"); break;
  }; break;
case 61: switch get_integer('"COLORADO" OR "DANGER-RADIOACTIVE EXCLUSION ZONE-AVOID"?##COLORADO (1), DANGER (2)',1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("2014-21"); break;
    case 2: X(62); break;
  }; break;
case 62: switch get_integer("DOES THE WARNING MENTION THE SPIDERS?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("2022"); break;
    case 2: show_message("2023 OR LATER"); break;
  }; break;
case 63: switch get_integer("SAUDI ARABIA?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("1922-32"); break;
    case 2: X(64); break;
  }; break;
case 64: switch get_integer("IS MOST OF WEST AFRICA A GIANT FRENCH BLOB?##YES (1), NO (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(49); break;
    case 2: X(65); break;
  }; break;
case 65: switch get_integer("HOW MANY VIETNAMS ARE THERE?##TWO (1), ONE (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(66); break;
    case 2: X(69); break;
  }; break;
case 66: switch get_integer("BANGLADESH?##NO (1), YES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(67); break;
    case 2: show_message("1972-75"); break;
  }; break;
case 67: switch get_integer("IS THE AREA SOUTH OF LAKE VICTORIA...##BRITISH (1), TANGANYIKA (2), TANZANIA (3)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(68); break;
    case 2: show_message("1961-64"); break;
    case 3: show_message("1965-71"); break;
  }; break;
case 68: switch get_integer("THE TOWN ON I-25 BETWEEN ALBUQUERQUE AND EL PASO IS...##HOT SPRINGS (1), TRUTH OR CONSEQUENCES (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("1948-49"); break;
    case 2: show_message("1950-52"); break;
  }; break;
case 69: switch get_integer("JIMMY CARTER IS...##BEING ATTACKED BY A GIANT SWIMMING RABBIT (1), FINE (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("APRIL 20, 1979"); break;
    case 2: X(70); break;
  }; break;
case 70: switch get_integer("THE SINAI IS PART OF WHAT COUNTRY?## ISRAEL (1), MOSTLY ISRAEL (2), MOSTLY EGYPT (3), EGYPT (4)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("1976-79"); break;
    case 2: show_message("1980"); break;
    case 3: show_message("1981"); break;
    case 4: X(71); break;
  }; break;
case 71: switch get_integer("WHAT'S THE CAPITAL OF MICRONESIA?## KOLONIA (1), PALIKIR (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(72); break;
    case 2: X(73); break;
  }; break;
case 72: switch get_integer("REPUBLIC OF THE UPPER VOLTA OR BURKINA FASO?## UPPER VOLTA (1), BURKINA FASO (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("1982-84"); break;
    case 2: show_message("1985-88"); break;
  }; break;
case 73: switch get_integer("(NUMBER OF YEMENS)+(NUMBER OF GERMANYS)=?## FOUR (1), THREE (2), TWO (3)",1)
  {
    case 1: show_message("1989-EARLY 1990"); break;
    case 2: show_message("MID-1990"); break;
    case 3: show_message("LATE 1990-1991"); break;
  }; break;
case 74: switch get_integer("DOES THE SOVIET UNION EXIST?## YES (1), NO (2)",1)
  {
    case 1: X(64); break;
    case 2: X(56); break;
  }; break;
}
```

**Numbering system**

- [Version 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCTNX.png): before reordering of `YES`, `NO` options to save bytes
- Version 2 (current): (reordered option numbers in black)

[image: Numbered map Version 2]

Comment: The options don't have to be in the order as in the image.

Comment: @corvus_192 Ah right, so I can always put `YES` first to avoid defining `N="##NO (1), YES (2)"`. Thanks.